# What should I do to have WS_MAXIMIZE working?

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, wndproc

There is how my program begins:

```
   int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
    {
        MapEditor mapEditor;

        mapEditor.Run();

        return 0;
    }
```

and there is MapEditor():

```
MapEditor::MapEditor()
{
    /* Creates the window */
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc=WinProc;
    wClass.cbClsExtra=NULL;
    wClass.cbWndExtra=NULL;
    wClass.hInstance=GetModuleHandle(0);
    wClass.hIcon=NULL;
    wClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    wClass.lpszClassName="Map Editor";
    wClass.hIconSm=NULL;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed to register window class","Window Class Failed",MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    ME_HWnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "Map Editor",
            "Map Editor",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            GetModuleHandle(0),
            this);

    if(!ME_HWnd)
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,"Window class creation failed","Window Class Failed",MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    ShowWindow(ME_HWnd, WS_MAXIMIZE);
}
```

The window won't ever start maximized. Why?

Answer (score 5):

You are passing the wrong second parameter to `ShowWindow`. The second parameter is supposed to be a `SW_...` value, not a `WS_...` value, as explained in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Wow! Thank you. What is even more shocking is that I found many people  reporting the same problem without receiving a solution.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron When all else fails, read the documentation. (The documentation is quite clear on the subject. Surprised it never occurred to you to check it.)

Comment: I did check it. I just didn't notice the swap in letters.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron Ha, I never noticed the swap. Here's the trick: WS = window style. SW = ShowWindow. This is a common pattern throughout Win32.